# best implementation for user group display differences

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I am developing a site in Wordpress that offers functionality and content to companies. 
Each company will have hundreds of users. All users of all companies get the same content.
However, the main header changes (it needs to include the companies own logo). They also will have their own sub-domain, at least fo the login page, preferably for all pages.
The content will change regularly, so I would prefer having only one copy of that.

So the requirements are:

- Same content for all users at same relative url
- Different header based on group of current user
- Different base url per group
- forwarding of user to the correct base url if they login under a wrong one

What is the best way to implement this?

- Straight WP with a sub-theme that deals with the header. Mod-rewrite to deal with the urls
- WP-MultiSite (how would the same content under different base urls work here?)
- Several copies of the site and somehow sync the content (how would I do the sync?)
- Use a different CMS

Which of these is the most future proof way to go, assuming I might have to deal with thousands of companies each with hundreds to thousands of users.

Also, If there is an easier way because I missed something in my research like an existing plugin, that would be great too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that such a thing depends on a lot more than these requirements. For instance, how granular would you like to have your user management? And how much are the users allowed to do on the different groups? Is unique information allowed on the different domains, or is all the information shared?

Based on the information you are providing, I think youy would be best off using the multisite version of wordpress. You then could use a broadcast plugin to share the information on all sites, and create a template site from which to create new sites (using the NS cloner plugin for instance).

There are of course some problems with this approach, for instance search engine optimisation. You will get a lot of duplicate content that will hurt the google ranking of the individual sites.

It would also be possible to do this using a single site install, but then you'll run into problems with the multiple domain structure. It can be done, but the available caching plugins will not support it (at least not that I know off), whereas a multisite environment is supported out of the box. It is also more difficult to keep users from posting on different domains, as they are using a single install. A multisite environment also has as shared user base, but they can be added or removed from the different sites at will.

Using a multisite environment would also allow you greater flexibility template-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are a few things in there that I have not thought of yet. I will look at the plugins. SEO is not a problem, as the content is not open to the public (or search-engines). +1 for now.